# How to get all associations of an entity without implementing a query for each relation?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We are developing a crm solution with spring and hibernate as backend technologies. In the domain layer we are a lot of entities among them the class Contact which is related to the most of the other entities (one way associations). Is there a tricky solution to get all Contact relations in class C1,C2....C1000 without implementing a query for each entity neither using joins that might be a bottelneck for application performance ?

```
public class Contact{  
//contact fields 
}

public class C1{
  Contact relationWithC1;
} 
.
.
.
 public class C1000{
  Contact relationWithC1000;
}
```

Comment: Hello Mejri, you can add eager so jpa does all queries. I wouldn't suggest that you search in one table because you can fall in a full table scan using joins and have query performance issues. Let spring figure it out to you https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading#Differences

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @heat thanks a lot for your reply. I updated my question with more details. My problem is that the class contact is spread in the domain layer. It is mentioned in most entity classes. Now, if I want to scan all entities related to a specific contact I have to implement a query for each entity class which is not practical especially for maintainability purposes. what do you suggest please ?